# Angular Nativescript apps can't use Kendo UI controls

Tags: telerik, angular2-nativescript, kendo-ui-angular2

Recently trying to create a mobile app only for iOS and android using Nativescript and Angular with Kendo UI.

Links like these https://www.nativescript.org/angular-connect seemed to me to imply that these Kendo controls could be available to be used in nativescript with the use of angular. However it seems that the controls are only available for web apps with the mobile controls being swapped out with nativescript ui controls in the views which is evident in this official demo.

https://github.com/telerik/ng2-dashboard

Attempts to follow getting started guides like https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/getting-started/ and importing plugins into apps created with Nativescript rather than Angular cli cause numerous errors mainly to do with documents and browsers not being available which I point down to the Kendo controls only being available for web apps.

Am i missing something here or are the Kendo UI controls specifically only for web based apps?